# Add notification sound file to exe in c#

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, resource-files

I'm trying to add a notification alarm when a user presses a button

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\.........\ambbrdg7.wav");
        simpleSound.Play();
    }
```

I want to add the **ambbrdg7.wav** to my exe file to make sure my program always has access to this file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Project + Properties, Resources tab, click on the arrow on the "Add Resource" button and select your .wav file.  Then it is simply:

```
var player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.Stream = Properties.Resources.tada;
player.Play();
```

where "tada.wav" was the resource I added, change it to your resource name.

Answer (score 1):

You either want to add the file as Content (add the file to your project and set it as Build Action -> Content) or add it as a resource - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: If you add it to your project and set it as Content then it should be the same path as your application, if you add it as a resource you would use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.80).aspx

Edit: @Hans Passant has the correct answer for Resources.